# Dynamically create object and memset it to 0

Tags: c++

Consider the following code.

```
class A
{
     private :
         int a;
     public : 
         void function1()
         {
              cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
         }
         void function2()
         {
              cout<<"bye bye world"<<endl;
         }
};
int main()
{
     A *obj = new A();
    memset(obj,0,sizeof(A));

    obj->function1();
    obj->function2();
    delete obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Shouldn't the function call should fail. When I try to run this code it runs perfectly fine.
Why memset doesn't have any effect on addresses of method?
Can you please explain whats is happening.

Comment: Functions aren't stored in each object. That would be a huge waste of space.

Comment: Why would you call memset() on a constructed object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the address of the function `&A::function1` and print it. Compare it to the address of the object `&obj`.

In memory the object itself only contains its non static data members and possibly a single vtable pointer.

The actual methods are code not data. They are shared among all objects and you cannot change them. Behind the scenes class methods are simply "special" functions that transparently accept the this pointer in addition to the arguments specified by the programmer.

That said you can really mess some objects up if you write over their internal state with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers do not store the member methods or static members with an instance of class.

That is why `memset` does not have any effect on address of method.

Answer (score 0):

"The actual methods are code not data. They are shared among all objects and you cannot change them. Behind the scenes class methods are simply "special" functions that transparently accept the this pointer in addition to the arguments specified by the programmer."

The above is correct, besides the fact that you are not trying to access any virtual function here and so the code works fine. If you make any of the methods virtual then the VPTR will be memset to NULL and there might be a segmentation fault (or undefined behavior).

Thanks
PRaveen